# Ajax window.location not working with PHP login Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a `PHP` login script which executes with ajax. The ajax request now starts the `session` in the login successfully but the `window.location` function doesn't work (doesn't redirect to `exporter.php`) in the ajax request. Below are my codes.

**php Login Script**

```
if(isset($_POST['log_name']) && isset($_POST['log_password'])) {

    $username = $_POST['log_name'];
    $password = $_POST['log_password'];

    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = ?");
    $sql->bindParam(1, $username, SQLITE3_TEXT);

    $ret = $sql->execute();

    while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
    {
        $id = $row['userid'];
        $regas = $row['regas'];
        $uemail = $row['uemail'];
        $pword = $row['pword'];
        $uname = $row['uname'];
        $package = $row['package'];

        if (password_verify($password, $pword))
        {


          $_SESSION['log_id'] = $id;
          $_SESSION['log_name'] = $username;
          $_SESSION['regas'] = $regas;
          $_SESSION['uemail'] = $uemail;
          $_SESSION['package'] = $package;
          //header("Location: index.php?log_id=$id");
          //echo "Sigining In...";
          //die("<script>window.location='exporter.php?userid={$id}';</script>");
          exit();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Information incorrect";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

**Ajax Request**

```
$("#submit_log").click(function() {
      //e.preventDefault();
      username=$("#log_name").val();
      password=$("#log_password").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: "log_name="+username+"&log_password="+password,
        success: function(html){
          if(html=='true')    {
            window.location.assign = "exporter.php";
          }
          else {
            $(".logresult").html('Incorrect Username and Password');
          }
        },
        beforeSend:function()
        {
          $(".logresult").html("Loading...")
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

**Beginning part of exporter.php**

```
session_start();
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();

if (!isset($_SESSION['log_name']) || !isset($_SESSION['log_id']) || !isset($_SESSION['regas']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

What could be wrong here and how do i fix this redirecting issue please!!!.Thanks.

Comment: You may want to use e.preventdefault(); for reference see: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your php login script needs `echo 'true';` according to your ajax callback.

and use `location.href = "/exporter.php";` to redirect page with JavaScript

Comment: Perfect answer. Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this:

```
window.location.href= "/exporter.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.assign = "exporter.php";
```

will not work, use

```
window.location = "exporter.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using assign incorrectly.

`window.location.assign("exporter.php")`

Or you can use href instead.

`window.location.href = "exporter.php";`

Answer (score 0):

Try using assign like this:

```
window.location.assign(data);
```

if this method not work for you let me know.

and if the Success:html is boolean then you're checking it in wrong way delete the single quotes it's not a string it is boolean datatype.

Comment: Neither method works. I am confused myself as where the issue is from.

Comment: please check that the if condition is being executed or not by using an alert() method.

Comment: @alen answer pointed out the issue with my php. Thanks for helping.